# Format DateTime Stamp Column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a `DateTime` column in MySQL.

I wonder how can I convert it into :

- UTC + 8 Timezone
- Format = `YYYY-MM-DD` 12 Hour format of the Timezone above

TYSM

Answer (score 1):

You can set it at runtime from the command line with

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+08:00'; #for UTC 
# And for time formate you can use as
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p') #for 12 hour format 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') #for 24 hour format
```

for add hour only in the query then

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')  as timeVal;
```

Comment: Sir please as much as possible no `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+08:00'; #for UTC` and I will use that only in select

Comment: then you can use an interval for the same if you want then i can explain how it works.check updated answer.

Comment: Please sir spare me a moment for that Im looking for something like this `SELECT convert_tz(12HourFormat(ColumnName)) FROM table`

Comment: But if your work with timezone then it will be a change for all the session or globally as per change. if you want to change only for the query you can go with the interval I suggest.

Comment: Yes thats what I need only the select no change globally only on the column of a specified row

Comment: Than use the below code which given in ans for add hour in time by interval.

Comment: I will test and back to you asap. tysm for help

Comment: Very clear answer. You can use a plus sign to add an interval to a date by the way. That would be `now() + interval 8 hour`, which I like much better than `date_add(now(), interval 8 hours)`.